# Where can I find info about rudimentary navigation / architecture paradigms?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, information-architecture

I need something that refers to classic approaches to structure content and the reason to choose them over others.

For example:

**Tabs** - use tabs when the different sections co exist and can be navigated to at any time.

**Wizard** - use a wizard when the sections depend on each other and need to be visited in a fixed order.

**Hub and spoke** - use when designing a UI that contains several discrete tasks or content but you don't want to link the sections to each other.

Jennifer Tidwell's [pattern repository](http://time-tripper.com/uipatterns/Overview_Plus_Detail) does this well.

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/donnam/information-architecture-patterns) by Donna Spencer is another example.

I 'd like to have more resources.

Comment: If you're talking about intranets, the Nielsen/Norman Group has a report including full IA examples. http://www.nngroup.com/reports/topic/information-architecture/

Answer (score 2):

You have a pretty wide question which takes a book to answer - so I'd recommend [Information Architecture for the World Wide Web: Designing Large-Scale Web Sites by Louis Rosenfeld and Peter Morville](http://books.google.se/books/about/Information_Architecture_for_the_World_W.html?id=OM3DvakML-MC&redir_esc=y).

[image: book cover]

It has everything you need when it comes to navigation patterns. But if you'd like something more light weight I'd suggest [Navigation patterns for ten common types of websites](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/11/navigation-patterns-for-ten-common-types-of-websites/) which is a really good introduction on the topic.

Next step, if your a real geek like me, take a [Bachelors Degree in Information Architecture at Malmo University](http://edu.mah.se/sv/Program/TIARK#Syllabus) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've already found Jennifer Tidwell's work - which would have been my first recommendation. Having a Google around for pattern libraries will probably provide some useful food for thought.

Take a look at the [Yahoo! design pattern library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) for example.

Comment: Nice link with a basic overview, thanks for sharing.